# Display div on hover

Tags: html, css

I've got a menu that looks something like this

```
   <nav role="navigation" class="small--hide">
    <ul class="site-nav">
        <li class="has-desktop-dropdown collection-dropdown">Link 1</li>
        <li>Link 2</li>
         <li class="has-desktop-dropdown journal-dropdown">Link 3</li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
```

Now I want a div to show when one of the list items is hovered

```
<div class="desktop-dropdown collection-dropdown-menu small--hide">
 <p>Some content</p>
</div>
<div class="desktop-dropdown journal-dropdown-menu small--hide">
 <p>Some content</p>
</div>
```

The Css I've been trying to use is this:

```
  .collection-dropdown:hover  ~ .collection-dropdown-menu {
    display:block;
  }
  .journal-dropdown:hover ~ .journal-dropdown-menu {
    display:block;
  }
```

But it's not showing the div on hover. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ckLf0gxt/3/#&togetherjs=exS2quS4qO)

Comment: You probably have a wrong understanding of what “sibling” means in DOM terms.

Comment: can you show your code in snippet !! and **do not** use `”` use `"` in `<li class=“has-desktop-dropdown journal-dropdown”>Link 3</li>`

Comment: You've shown two separate elements without showing where they are in the document in relation to each other. How did you expect us to help?

Comment: I believe for tilde operator to work the later has to be the sibling of the former. That doesn't seem to be the case with you.

Comment: Here is working fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/ckLf0gxt/12/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work like that. In CSS `sibling` meaning the adjacent elements of a particular dom element. In your question, `collection-dropdown` doesn't have a sibling of class `collection-dropdown-menu`.

```css
.collection-dropdown-menu, .journal-dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}
.navigation {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.navigation:hover  ~ .collection-dropdown-menu, 
.navigation:hover ~ .journal-dropdown-menu {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
 <nav role="navigation" class="navigation small--hide">
    <ul class="site-nav">
        <li class='has-desktop-dropdown collection-dropdown'>Link 1</li>
        <li>Link 2</li>
        <li class='has-desktop-dropdown journal-dropdown'>Link 3</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="desktop-dropdown collection-dropdown-menu small--hide">
 <p>Some content</p>
</div>
<div class="desktop-dropdown journal-dropdown-menu small--hide">
 <p>Some content</p>
</div>
```

Please watch how this works

In this example, the `nav` with classname `.navigation` has siblings `collection-dropdown-menu` and `journal-dropdown-menu`. But these are not siblings for `collection-dropdown` which is an inner element of `navigation`. So I have added the `hover` styles in `navigation` and so that works